# Java EventHandler not working, why does it create new Frame?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, events, handler

I am trying to create an address book for a uni project and I am trying to get the GUI to be able to save the details that are input to the form to a file. Every time I click save on the GUI it creates a new Frame rather than executing the code that I have put in the even Handler. I am still fairly new to Java and I just can't see what is wrong with it.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;


public class AddressBook {


static AddressBookGui addressBookGui = new AddressBookGui();

static int writeCount;

File detailsFile = new File("customerDetails.txt");


public static void saveDetails() throws IOException {

    String title = addressBookGui.txtTitle.getText();

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("customerDetails.txt");
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw);

    out.println(title);


    out.close();

    writeCount++;
    }

}
```

Above is the Handler class, below is the GUI.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class AddressBookGui {

private JLabel lblTitle;
public JTextField txtTitle;
private JButton btnSaveDetails;
private JPanel panel;
private JFrame frame;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new AddressBookGui();
}

public AddressBookGui() {

    createPanel();
    addLabels();
    addTextFields();
    addButtons();

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void createPanel() {

    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Address Book");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(800,950);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(null);
}

public void addLabels() {

    lblTitle = new JLabel("Title");
    lblTitle.setBounds(90,210,140,30);
    panel.add(lblTitle);

}

public void addTextFields() {

    txtTitle = new JTextField("");
    txtTitle.setBounds(190,210,150,30);
    panel.add(txtTitle);

}
public void addButtons() {

    btnSaveDetails = new JButton("Save");
    btnSaveDetails.setBounds(200,600,80,30);
    btnSaveDetails.addActionListener(new SaveDetailsButton());
    panel.add(btnSaveDetails);

}


public class SaveDetailsButton implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        try {
            AddressBook.saveDetails();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File did not write correctly.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

}

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: Do you have an action in your code that makes a Frame to be openned ? It might sound dumb, but if your listener is not called, you are simply not triggering the right button. Identify which action is executed when you click, and finally find out why it is executed in place of your listener

Comment: Revised code posted in the question section. This will run in Eclipse but will just create a new frame rather than a new file and write to it.